# CSS3 transform: scaling results in translation?

Tags: html, css, transformation, scaling

I have the following simple HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 30px;
      }
      a {
        display: block;
      }
      a:hover {
        transform: scale(2); 
        transition: all 4s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href=#>Link</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

in which the `Link` is supposed to scale. However, it shifts to the left. What is the problem?

Comment: You could also use `font-size: 2em;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  padding:30px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 4s;
}
a:hover {
  transform: scale(2); 
}
```

```html
<a href=#>Link</a>
```

You should have used **display:inline-block** to make it work. If it is what you are looking for, +1.

Comment: I worked like a charm! Would you kindly explain why it is this way?

Comment: The <a> element is an [inline-block element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

Comment: Answering my own question: I think the problem with `display: block;` is that the width of the block is the same as that of `<body>` and doubling it results in a quite large width. Hence, we see the `Link` shifts to the left.